# Scala Backward Compatibility

Tags: scala, compatibility, binary-compatibility

What changes or code evolution break backward compatibility (mainly binary compatibility)?  Is it fully specified anywhere?

I checked the [Scala language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), but didn't see any section on the matter like [Java Language Specification Ch. 13 Binary Compatibility](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/binaryComp.html).

Comment: Please refer to the specific version jumps you are referring to for future reference.

Comment: @Raphael, my question wasn't specific to the Scala library.  It was about what changes can I do to my own code that break compatibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the mailing list, the spec documenting detailing backward compatibility issues [does not yet exist](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala.user/40548) but is in the works.

For current status and oulook of binary compatibility (mainly of the scala library), see [Martin's message](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala.user/39290) to scala-user mailing list.

For a migration manager preview, see this page http://typesafe.com/technology/migration-manager.

Answer (score 1):

I've added support for Scala to the *japi-compliance-checker* tool (*1.6* version). So now you can identify breaking changes in your code automatically. The tool is available here: https://github.com/lvc/japi-compliance-checker

Sample usage:

```
japi-compliance-checker OLD.jar NEW.jar
```

Also I've created a page with analysis reports for Scala versions evolution generated by this tool as an example: http://abi-laboratory.pro/java/tracker/timeline/scala/

[image]