# Is Scala incompatible with itself?

Tags: scala

Is Scala incompatible with itself at times?

ie. you are using the latest build, but using a scala based jar that is built on an older version?

or maybe I am not presenting the scenerio correctly, but if someone experienced with Scala can tell me if there are issues with versioning of some sort that is something like what I am trying to describe (I read this somewhere but wasn't sure what they were talking about).

Comment: The term you are looking form is called `binary incompatibility` and your question is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053265/scala-binary-incompatibility-between-releases

Comment: @serejja The primary reply/replies in that addresses a different question, which assumes the [application] source code is changed ..

Comment: I think the question "Is Scala backwards compatible?" would be more apt; [backwards compatible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_compatibility) means the *new* environment will still work with the *old* things.

Comment: Ref. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244103/scala-backward-compatibility

Comment: @user2864740: somehow the links seem swapped. The answer linked by serejja explains why Scala releases are not binary compatible with each other, and it seems more related to the scenario the OP hints at. The question *you* linked discusses what happens if a (Scala) application changes.