# Scala: Classfile-level interoperability from 2.12 to 2.13? vice versa?

Tags: scala, sbt, binary-compatibility

Can Scala 2.12 project can call methods in classfile compiled in Scala 2.13? and vice versa?

I'm going to updating our large Scala product from 2.12 to 2.13. The product is made of a few sbt project (currently all of these are built with 2.12) and projects are depending each other.

Can I update one of project upto 2.13 leaving other project as 2.12? or I must update all of project upto 2.13 at one time?

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/binary-compatibility-of-scala-releases.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053265/scala-binary-incompatibility-between-releases https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244103/scala-backward-compatibility

Comment: No, you can't. Each major version of the language is incompatible with the other ones. **Scala 3** will use a different model.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by project but you can also cross compile to both 2.12 and 2.13 for a progressive upgrade.